# Add borders to photos while inserting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a tool to streamline writing a report for my company.  This report requires a number of photos to be inserted, resized, and explained.  I have created a table in Excel to explain the photos and wrote some VBA code based on a similar report that we use.  In order to maintain formatting between the Excel generated report and the Word generated report I need to add a border to the pictures and would like to do this as the photos are imported.

Can anyone help me with this?

The remainder of the 'If' statement resizes the photo.

```
Sub Pic() ' 'Pic Macro ' Dim PLog As String Dim Photo As String Dim a
As Integer Dim b As Integer Dim c As Integer Dim d As Integer Dim
Bottom As String Dim bot As Integer Dim PrintA As String Dim Top As
String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False Sheets("Photo Log").Select

a = 5 b = 1

PLog = "PLog" & b Photo = "Input!Q" & a

While a < 152

PLog = "PLog" & b Photo = "Input!Q" & a

If Range(Photo) <> "" Then

     Range("PLog1").Select

     ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert( _
         Range("PhotoPath") & "\" & Range("SiteID") & " (" & Range(Photo) & ").jpg" _
         ).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all use the `Shape` object when you are inserting the image. Avoid the use of `.Select`. Secondly use the shape's `.Line.Weight` and `.Line.Visible` to get that border.

```
'
'~~> Rest of the code
'

Dim MyPic As Shape

Set MyPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Range("PhotoPath") & "\" & _
                                        Range("SiteID") & " (" & _
                                        Range(Photo) & ").jpg" _
                                        )
'~~> Insert Border
With MyPic
    .Line.Weight = 8
    .Line.Visible = msoTrue
End With

'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
```